# Not able to fire event in WinJS

Tags: javascript, html, winjs

Here is my code. I want to fire the click event of the button but not able to fire please let me know where I am wrong:

```
//Html
  <div style="margin-top:78px; margin-left:970px;">
            <button id="saveBtn"  type="submit" name="saveBtn">Clear</button>    
        </div>

//Js event listener
  var BtnClick = document.getElementById("saveBtn");
            BtnClick.addEventListener("click", ClearTextHandler, false);


 //function 

    function ClearTextHandler(mouseEvent)
    {
        var message_dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Sorry, we were unable to log you in!" + mouseEvent.y.toString()).showAsync();
    }
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What error did you get? Are you developing a UWP(JS) App?

Comment: I am developing applications for the Windows Store with a consistent look and performance across all Windows devices using *WINJS*

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", function(){ClearTextHandler(event)}, false);
```

Comment: Please explain little bit; How it's working and how it's different from OP;

Answer (score -1):

You have to define your ClearTextHandler function **before** you set the EventListener. You have to define function before you can use it. Just like variables. Hope this helps.

e.g like this:

```
    function ClearTextHandler(mouseEvent) {
            var message_dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Sorry, we were unable to log you in!" + mouseEvent.y.toString()).showAsync();
    }     
    var BtnClick = document.getElementById("saveBtn");
    BtnClick.addEventListener("click", ClearTextHandler, false);
```

Comment: I am calling addEventListener in ready function so its not making any sense to call the function before ready.